# CreateRadialplot with flip angle label

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope to flip angle the label. I use the popular functon CreateRadialplot to obtain a circular plot with ggplot2. [Link to the site](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/5795_e6e6411731bb4f1b9cc7eb49499c2082.html). Now i obtain this, look at the plot below.
[image]
Someone can help me with this function to flip angle of the labels rather than horizontal labels as showed here?
sample code who called the function:

````
var.names <- c("All Flats", "No central heating", "Rooms per\nhousehold", "People per room", 
  "HE Qualification", "Routine/Semi-Routine\nOccupation", "2+ Car household", 
  "Public Transport\nto work", "Work from home")
values.a <- c(-0.1145725, -0.1824095, -0.01153078, -0.0202474, 0.05138737, -0.1557234, 
  0.1099018, -0.05310315, 0.0182626)
values.b <- c(0.2808439, -0.2936949, -0.1925846, 0.08910815, -0.03468011, 0.07385727, 
  -0.07228813, 0.1501105, -0.06800127)

group.names <- c("Blue Collar Communities", "Prospering Suburbs")
m2 <- matrix(c(values.a, values.b), nrow = 2, ncol = 9, byrow = TRUE)
group.names <- c(group.names)
df2 <- data.frame(group = group.names, m2)
colnames(df2)[2:10] <- var.names

CreateRadialPlot(group.line.width = df2, plot.extent.x = 1.5)```
````

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that's easy for folks to answer—including code and representative samples of data

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you want to change. Are you talking about the text labels on the plot? Do you want them to extend out from the plot (parallel to the radial axes that they refer to) instead of all being horizontal (aligned to the bottom of the plot)?

Comment: sorry if isn't clear, i'm talking about the text labels on the plot, not the text on legend. I would like label parallel to the radial axes that they refer to exactly